# want to add bootstrap in django forms builder

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using django form builder library. [Form builder](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder/tree/master/forms_builder/example_project)

I am getting forms in front end but i want add bootstrap in that forms.
Normal form i am getting is 
[image]

Now i want to give the look and feel to form using bootstrap. I am not able to get this html file.

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

To make form looks bootstrap way you have to add CSS classes (at least class="form-control" for inputs and class="btn btn-default" for submit). According to the doc https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder it is possible.